# Databricks Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same target row in the Delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, merge, azure-databricks

I am attempting to do a merge with Databricks but I'm getting the error:

```
UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same
target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting ways.
```

I have seen this issue many times on SO, and I understand that a merge operation can fail if multiple rows of the source dataset match and the merge attempts to update the same rows of the target Delta table.

In plain English this happens when the source table has multiple rows trying to update the same target row. This could happen if the updates table has records with the same ID. In my case I don't think that applies.

Can someone take a look at my code and let me know where if they can spot anything obvious

```
(deltadf.alias("t")
     .merge(
      df.alias("s"),
      "s.primary_key_hash = t.primary_key_hash")
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll("s.change_key_hash <> t.change_key_hash")
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
   .execute()
  )
```

sample deltadf

[image]

Sample df

[image]

Please forgive the images.. I'm struggling to with adding data with Markup language

Comment: Can you edit the question to include sample data of `deltadf` and `df`

Comment: Hi Saideep, thanks for getting in touch. I have added an image of the sample data for deltadf and df. Sorry about adding images.

Comment: just compare `deltadf.count()` and `deltadf.dropDuplicates("prinary_key_hash").count()` - if they are different, then you have duplicates in your input data, and you need to get rid of them

Comment: I must admit that I am executing the code without updating the input data. What I mean by that is, when I execute the merge the first time its without any issues. However, when I execute the merge the second time without updating the input data I get the error. Do you think that is why I'm getting the problem.

Comment: Hi Alex, when I execute deltadf.count() I get the error 'DeltaTable' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: `DeltaTable` object does not have `count()` or `dropDuplicates()` as these are attributes of a `DataFrame` object.

Comment: I also am having similar behavior with Databricks/Spark. I have an instance where a series of streaming jobs that merge fine suddenly fail with this error on the 2nd, or in one case 4th, run and then fail from them on. I've been unable to narrow the case when it happens; it mostly seems to run fine, then suddenly fails and never works again for multiple tasks. I'm continuing to debug to try and identify what might be the cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this issue and the following are the delta table data and input dataframe data.

- Delta table:

[image]

- Input dataframe:

[image]

There are duplicates for `hash_key` in the input dataframe. When I try to use merge on these delta table and the source dataframe, it throws the error.

```
deltadf.alias("t").merge(df.alias("s"),"s.hash_key = t.hash_key")\ 
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll("s.change_key <> t.change_key")\ 
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()\ 
   .execute()
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and 
attempted to modify the same target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting ways. By SQL 
semantics of Merge, when multiple source rows match on the same target row, the result may be 
ambiguous as it is unclear which source row should be used to update or delete the matching target 
row. You can preprocess the source table to eliminate the possibility of multiple matches.
```

We can see in the error that we need to **preprocess the source to eliminate the possibility of multiple matches** which is the case here. So, please try to check for duplicate values in your dataframe `df` and drop them using `df.dropDuplicates('primary_key_hash')`. Since you are matching using `primary_key_hash`, make sure there are no duplicate values in this column of the dataframe.

> when I execute the merge the first time its without any issues.
> However, when I execute the merge the second time without updating the
> input data I get the error. Do you think that is why I'm getting the
> problem.

No, if the merge operation is executed successfully for the first time and you use the same input for the 2nd execution as well, it would run without any error because `primary_key_hash` would be matched and the `change_key_hash` will be updated without any inserts this time (because new `primary_key_hash` are inserted in previous run when not matched).

Comment: The fourth comment above from @Patterson would seem to suggest different behavior than what your last point describes. I also am getting similar behavior to what Patterson describes. I'm still trying to narrow down if there are special circumstances when it occurs.

Comment: Saiddeep, you make good point, because I don't have df.dropDuplicates('primary_key_hash'), however I don't understand why it works the first time but not the second time. T.Shaffner, thanks for helping out

Comment: This might be a special case that you are facing. The solution given helps to overcome the error in general.

Comment: So, Saideep are you referring to duplicate hash shown in my image?

Comment: In the solution, yes. If there are duplicates in `primary_key_hash` in `df` dataframe, then it will give the error.

Comment: So, are you saying I need to add the following ... df.dropDuplicates('primary_key_hash') ?

Comment: Yeah, try doing that, `df = df.dropDuplicates('primary_key_hash')` and then try to use merge

Comment: I will try that now, I really hope that works

Comment: @SaideepArikontham-MT, if a dropDuplicates is done and duplicates actually occur, won't that mean there's a risk of real data getting lost? There are cases where this error is an important warning of data problems; dropping duplicates first seems like it would remove the value of that error without addressing the case here, in which it seems to occur without duplicates existing. If there are real duplicates, dropping might drop the wrong ones, correct?

Comment: That will be an issue. We can consider dropping only if the entire row is a duplicate. If only the key column has duplicates, then we need to process data in such a way that there won't be any duplicates without dropping them. If this is not does not work for you, `merge` might not be the right choice.

Comment: I really don't understand why it fails by executing the merge code a second time

Comment: Hi Saideep, I'm still getting the error. Are you able to move to chat to help me?

Comment: It is unclear about why the merge would fail the second time after successfully running the first time @Patterson

Comment: I entered df.dropDuplicates('primary_key_hash') but I got the error "TypeError: Parameter 'subset' must be a list of columns"

Comment: try df.dropDuplicates(['primary_key_hash'])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246034/discussion-between-saideeparikontham-mt-and-patterson).

Comment: @Patterson, you all find any result here that might narrow down the case where this occurs?

Comment: Hi T Shaffner, unfortunately I couldnt find any solution to this

Comment: @Patterson, in my case I seem to have managed to stop the behavior (so far), and the best theory I have is that some kind of corruption may have gotten into the process when multiple jobs were touching the same tables at the same time. After it occurred once it never worked again, which seems corruption-like. I haven't been able to verify with 100% certainty that this is the cause, but wiping then recreating all the tables and careful scheduling to avoid overlapping runs has so far left me without a recurrence. Maybe try that and see if it helps you too?

Comment: Hi T.Shaffner, thanks for that. I wil try that out, and let you know how I get on. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and figured out the problem was the first time it worked. My data source indeed had duplicates on my primary_key so the second time I ran the code I got the error of multiple rows.
Once I cleared the destination table and the source df, it worked every time.